# dynamic object pointer array C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I want to make a pointer array that holds address of instances of that class so when I call my `scanner` function it will search for objects that have the same `pcode` and print them. I kind of did that but now when I try to use different inherited class objects I get a "memory access violation" and I can't access the inherited class functions through the base static scan function.

sorry for the mess here is my code

```
using namespace std;
class product{
    public:
        product();
        product(long&,string&);
        void const printer();
        void setCode();
        void getCode(long);

        void static scanner();
        static product *point; //when this was static did compile but not now
        static  int a;
    private:
        string pname;
        long pcode;

};
class PrepackedFood:public product{
    //snip
private:
    double uPrice;
};
class FreshFood:public product{
    //snip
private:
    double weight;
    double pricepk;
};
```

product.cpp

```
product *product::point=new product [15];  //when i use try to use dynamic cant
int product::a(0);   

product::product(){
    pcode=0;
    pname="unknown";            
    point[a]= this;                            //here works for normal arrays not now
    a++;
}
product::product(long& c,string&n){
    pcode=c;
    pname=n;
}
void product::scanner(){
    long a;
    int i=0;
    while(i<3){
        if (point[i]->pcode==a){
            point[i]->printer();
            break;
        }
        i++;    
    }
}
void product::setCode(){ 
    cout<<"enter product name\n  ";
    cin>>pname;
    cout<<"enter product code _____\b\b\b\b\b\a";
    cin>>pcode;
}

//blah blah for other members
```

main.cpp

```
#include "product.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int i=0;
    cout<<"enter fresh foods"<<endl;
    FreshFood f[3];

    for(int a=0;a<3;a++)
        f[i].setCode();
    product::scanner();

    return 0;
}
```

Is it a memory address problem or something entirely different?  And why does `scan{this->print()}` call the base function?  Is there a way to call the inherited `print()` function?

Comment: Please trim your code down to the smallest reproducible sample.  There is a lot of code in there which is completely irrelevant.

Comment: sorry i am really tired don't know which is relevant

Comment: Well that's your job, your end of the bargain. You need help, not us, so you should make it easy for us to help you.  You don't get to hand off the job of testing completely to us.  It is perfectly reasonable to expect you to have done some work before posting here.

Comment: yup but i am new to c++ my code is a mess in my first post was i trimmed but ppl didn't understand what my code is for until i post it all. anyways i have to sleep i guess 5 hrs left i have to give boring version this doesn't seem to finish.

Comment: Well, it's just basic troubleshooting; you isolate the problem and disregard everything else.  You can reproduce your issue in a few lines of code once you have done that.  Now of course you may not understand *why* it is wrong, in which case, you come here and ask us.

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now that I finally simplified your question text, here's the answer:

- `void const printer();` This doesn't compile.  If you want calls to a function to call that of the most derived type, you must mark the function `virtual`.  Also, the `const` goes *after* the name.
- `void setCode();` It's generally not a good idea for a store product to read from the console directly.  It's job is to be an item, and items don't parse numbers.  An external function should parse the input.
- `static product *point;` This should probably be replaced with a `std::vector<product*>`.  That is a dynamic array of pointers to individual products.  Pointers to each product allows the polymorphism of `virtual` functions to work how you want them to.
- `product *product::point=new product [15];` creates an array of 15 `product` objects.  Not `PrepackedFood`, or any other type of object, these are *only* `products`.  No more or less. Also, you're leaking this memory.  Use a `vector`
- `point[a]= this;` This doesn't even compile, since `point[a]` is a `product`, and `this` is a pointer.
- `product::product(long& c,string&n)` This function doesn't register the product.  Any products made with this aren't registered in your array and cannot be found.  Luckily, you aren't using it.
- `void getCode(long) {` I'm not even sure what this code does it's so bad.
- `void product::scanner(){` Use a for loop instead of a while loop, that's just confusing.  Also, you're only scanning the first three items made, it should probably scan all of the ones made.  Using a `vector` would help here.
- If a `product` is ever destroyed (which is very very common), then this entire design will fail and fixing that is going to be very complicated.  I don't know what you're doing but I recommend that you stop now.

Did I get all of it?

Comment: don't know about vectors yet so i have no idea atm i ll look in to that

Comment: that first code was //static product *point[3]; //product* product::point[3]; did compile and worked but when inherited afew class memory leaked and i tried to use dynamic but i have to change it to compile //point[a]= *this; and it didn't compile in my mind :D

Comment: anyways thanks for the help ill try to finish with vectors in afew days

Comment: i thought //*this was the object and //this  is a address of the object

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to try to implement your "array" using a container. std::list would be a good start. Have a look [at this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stllist.html), scroll down to the example with a for loop, this should help you to clean up your code and fix memory access issues. Keep in mind that you can store whole objects in your list, not just pointers to them.
Also, you may try to decouple your data from your code. Try using a struct for your data.

Comment: `list`?  I've never seen a situation yet where `std::list` was the best container. (though I acknowledge their potential existence)  `std::vector` or `std::map` for this code I think.  Decoupling the data and the code seems like a bad idea.  Why would you recommend that?

Comment: I have suggested `list` as a simple one to understand containers and more importantly iterators. Same principle applies re decoupling suggestion -- @meh needs some "space" in his code, as it seems to me that currently he has overly complex solution for what he is doing. He **may** not need to use inheritance, but rather have a flag in a struct for such simple task.

Comment: Replacing his array with a `std::list` will exhibit all of the same problems of the current code.  That fixes nothing.  Storing whole objects in the container _is the problem_.

Comment: What I am suggesting is to let the container to manage memory, going away from arrays and pointers will do just that. Where using pointers requires to manage memory manually (with the results mentioned by the topic starter). And if we go this way, automatic pointers should be brought in at the least...

Comment: The container _shouldn't_ be managing memory, nor should there be manual memory management.  The container should contain raw pointers to objects that have automatic duration from the looks of his code.